# Airlines overbooking probability problem

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Airlines regularly overbook flights to compensate for no-show passengers. In doing so, airlines are balancing the risk of having to compensate bumped passengers against lost revenue associated with empty seats.

It was found that the average no-show rate was $12\%$. An airline books $110$ passengers on a $100$-seat plane. Assume a $12\%$ probability that a passenger will not show up for boarding.

The airline makes a profit of $\$100$ per passenger on this flight, and it estimates the cost of a bumped passenger to be $\$1000$. For this reason, the airline would like a probability of
at least $0.9$ that no passenger will be bumped. How many tickets should the airline sell on this
$100$-seat plane?

Could anyone guide on the solving this problem?

Comment: Formatting note:  you can't use dollar signs to denote currency in a straight forward way,  as those symbols have meaning within the typesetting system used by the site.  If you click on "Edit" you can see the syntax I used to insert the symbols you wanted.

Comment: For reference, [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial on formatting for this site.

Comment: If the airline sells $n$ seats, where $n > 100$, then you want that the probability of $(n - 101)$ or less *no-shows* is $\leq (1/10)$.  See [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), 
specifically $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}p^kq^{(n-k)}.$  Also, your question will probably cause mathSE reviewers to react negatively, rather than positively.  If you are interested in having mathSE reviewers react positively, instead, see [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Comment: Note: re my previous comment, there may be an easier approach than assuming a Binomial Distribution.  I am virtually ignorant of Statistics (i.e. standard deviations, et al).  One of the missing items from your question is : what is the source of the problem?  That is, are you currently studying Statistics?